# How do I make component not visible in UI even when it is in the DOM?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function `printDocument` that **onClick** downloads the **pdf** that has the content of `<ComponentViewToDownload/>`. I do not want to show that component in the UI, just **Download** button. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
     render() {
        return (
           <div>
             <button onClick={this.printDocument}>Download</button>
             <div id="divToPrint" >
               <ComponentViewToDownload/>
             </div>
           </div>
        );
     }
```

Comment: Does it work if you write `<div id="divToPrint" style={{ display: "none" }}>`?

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Comment: That's frustrating. You could do something silly like `<div id="divToPrint" style={{ marginLeft: "9999px" }}>` and see if that works.

Comment: Add overflow as hidden to div having id divToPrint along with Tholle's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      top: "-9999px",
      left: "-9999px"
    }}
```

Works well and doesn't mess up the main UI layout